# BarButtonItem change after segue is visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, segue

I have an app with a navigation controller that does a segue to another view controller and then checks for the presence of an object in viewDidLoad (that may or may not exist). It then updates the name of a barButtonItem if the object exists. The problem is I can see the button expanding to accommodate the new name as the segue occurs.

How can I make this button change before the view is loaded so this jumping button effect is not seen? Shouldn't changes made in viewDidLoad not be seen until after viewDidAppear?

Comment: You are right. viewDidLoad is invoked (or should be) after performeSegue (of the calling VC) and before viewWillAppear. Even changes made in viewWillAppear should come into effect well before the view gets visible for the first time. Do you set the text value directly in viewDidLoad? Or do you use core data as well and set its value in configureView? If so then bare in mind that configureView is not only called by viewDidLoad. It is called from the setter of the detailItem as well - so every time when the value of the detailItem changes.

Comment: Hmm... I couldn't duplicate this -- I'm not seeing the button grow. Is there any reason that the check for the objects presence should take a long time (relatively speaking)?

Comment: I think I see why now. viewDidLoad calls a method that looks up the object in Core Data on a different thread. The view must have already loaded by the time the object is returned and so the title change is noticeable. Not sure that there is a way around this.